# Modifying an array of pointers through a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying code a function cpyMsg() that makes copies of messages to an array of pointers. But I'm having an Bad Access memory error and I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

Example:

```
int cpyMsg(char **m, char *msg, size_t *dim){

     m = realloc(m, (*dim + 1) * sizeof(char *));
     m[*dim] = malloc(strlen(msg)+1);
     strcpy(m[*dim], msg);
     (*dim)++;
     return 1;
}

int main() {

     char msg[] = "Test Message";
     char **m = NULL;
     size_t dim = 0;
     cpyMsg(m, msg, &dim);
     printf("m[%lu] = %s\n", dim-1, m[dim-1]); //<- EXC_BAD_ACCESS
     return 0;
}
```

If I put all the code inside the main function, it works just fine, but it doesn't in the cpyMsg() function. Am I passing wrong the argument "char **m"?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In `main()` you declare a variable named `m`, initialize it to `NULL` and pass **its value** to the function `cpyMsg()`. The function `cpyMsg()` does whatever it does but when it returns the variable `m` has exactly the save value which it had before the function was called, which is `NULL`. In the next statement you try to dereference a NULL pointer, hence segmentration violation, memory access error, whatever...

Comment: The `**m` in the function is a *copy* of the `**m` in `main`, which is not modified. One solution would be a three-star parameter (not advised), better would be to return the pointer as the function value, with `NULL` to indicate failure.

Comment: Aside: use `%zu` to print a `size_t` variable, not `%lu`.